# Potentiometer for two 12V/1.1A fans in parallel

Tags: potentiometer

I recently bought a potentiometer to regulate the speed of two 12V/1.1A DC fans in parallel, powered by a 12V source. Its specifications are the following:

#### Resistance= 10k Ohm, MaxPower = 0.2W.

Can I connect the fans, the potentiometer and the power source in series, or do I need additional circuitry to avoid circuit damage? I feel like the potentiometer's maximum power is too low, but I may be wrong.

Comment: You want a smaller pot to start with.  If you try to push 2A through 10K, you'll need 20,000V.

Comment: [This is what you want](https://www.ebay.com/itm/12V-40V-10A-Pulse-Width-Modulator-PWM-DC-Motor-Speed-Control-Switch-ControllerCH/123120992878) to control your fans. A suitable potentiometer for the job is crazy big.

Comment: Thanks @CristobolPolychronopolis, that was one of my main concerns. Unfortunately that leads to another problem, which is: The cheapest potentiometers had a lot of resistance to begin with. I imagined that for two fans in parallel, which is a pretty simple circuit, potentiometer prices would correspond to the cheapest and not the way around, so I'm kind of confused.

Comment: No, no, no this won't work - smoke will erupt. Pots are used to control milli amps at most and not amps.

Comment: I guess I will try the PWM controller that @lakeweb suggested, instead. Thanks for saving my life :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 10 kohm pot rated at 0.2 watts then, end-to-end you could apply 44.7 volts across it - that would take a current of 4.47 mA. Reason: -

Power = Voltage\$^2\$/Resistance hence voltage = \$\sqrt{P\cdot R}\$ = 44.7 volts.

That's the maximum current the pot can be used for.

Even if you only used one-tenth the range of the pot (1 kohm) i.e. you used it like a rheostat, the power is also reduced by one-tenth to 20 mW and the maximum voltage across one tenth is 4.47 volts. Guess what... the current is still 4.47 mA.

```
4.47 mA is the maximum current you can pass through a 10 kohm 200 mW pot.
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, but isn't the pot supposed to have variable resistance? I thought the 10kohm were the maximum resistance, when there's almost no current and the fans are turned off.

Comment: My answer has shown that no matter what position the wiper is, the maximum current that can be passed through a small section is 4.47 mA. If you are only using one-tenth the range of the pot, 90% is unused and therefore the power rating that applies to the section that is used MUST BE one-tenth of 200 mW i.e. 20 mW.

Comment: Apart from anything else a 10 k pot (even if it had a decent power rating) would be wholly unsuitable to regulate the fans. You would be looking for something like a 10 ohm pot to regulate to a bit below half speed and this is wire wound and is therefore costly and if you do the math you'll find that when you are pushing 2 amps through a 10% section (fans at high speed) that power dissipation is 4 watts. Thus the fan would need an overall rating of 40 watts!

Answer (score 1):

In today's world electronic controls for this kind of work are the only way to go. And thanks to cheap products on Ebay, there is a solution. I'm sure this is cheaper than a pot that would work. And, it is way more efficient.

[Ebay Product to do the job](https://www.ebay.com/itm/12V-40V-10A-Pulse-Width-Modulator-PWM-DC-Motor-Speed-Control-Switch-ControllerCH/123120992878)

[image]